# Adding a new Auth source to spree_social

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using the 1-3-stable version of spree_social to (try to) add a custom authentication method provided by another application of mine (I already tested it with a dummy client following omniauth conventions and it's working).
Unfortunately I can't find any guideline about how I could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently it's just a matter of forking the gem, clone it, and trying to replicate what has been done for other providers.
In particular:

- create a gem for your provider or at least a file in spree_social/lib, defining the endpoints of your application (authorize and access token urls).
- add such a file/gem in your lib/spree_social.rb file
- add your icons in app/assets/images/store
- if needed, provide your custom callback in app/controllers/spree/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
- cross your finger.